# Can we pass argument to function & access like a props in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, functional-programming

I have started learning to React/JavaScript recently, I found the way props are passed and accessed very interesting, I tried to make a similar JavaScript function in react which can simply take arguments & can access the passed argument as we do in react but wasn't able to do that (Assume I just wanted to log the arguments on console).

> Something like this:

```
const fun = ({ name = '', subjects = '', university = '' }) => { 
  console.log('Name       : ', name)
  console.log('Subjects   : ', subjects)
  console.log('University : ', university)
}
```

> React Example

```
import React from 'react';

const Comp = ({ name = '', subjects = '', university = '' }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Name : {name}</p>
      <p>Subjects : {subjects}</p>
      <p>University : {university}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <Comp subjects="Computer Science" />
      <Comp subject="Computer Science" name="wasit" />
      <Comp
        subject="Computer Science"
        university="Jamia Millia Islamia"
        location='New Delhi, India'
        name="wasit"
      />
      <Comp
        name="wasit"
        subject="Computer Science"
        university="Jamia Millia Islamia"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If someone can guide me in the right direction, I will be thankful to you all...

Sample Code:

```js
const fun = (name = 'defaultName', subjects = 'defaultSubjects', university = 'defaultUniversity') => {
  console.log('name : ', name)
  console.log('subjects : ', subjects)
  console.log('university : ', university)
}

console.clear()
fun()
console.log('******************************')

fun(name = 'name1')
console.log('******************************')

fun(university = 'university2', name = 'name2')
console.log('******************************')

fun(university = 'university3', subjects = 'subject3', name = 'name3')
// or just simply
// fun('university3', 'subject3', 'name3')
console.log('******************************')

// Error because function is expecting max 3 arguments, which is not the case in react
//fun(university = 'university4', location = 'location4', subjects = 'subject4', name = 'name4')
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>React VS JS</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Please checkout JavaScript!!
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over each key in the object

```js
const print = props => {
    for (let key in props)
        console.log(`${key}: ${props[key]}`);
};

print({name: 'Ken Roczen', number: 94});

// name: Ken Roczen
// number: 94
```

Comment: Yes, the above method can be one of the ways to simulate argument/parameters like a **Props** but still, we will be limited to several features of **React Props** eg, **Destructuring Props**

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the parentheses outside the parameters, and in the single quotes after the "=" mark, you can set default value in it, if you call the function without passing the parameters you will just get your defaults values in your console.

Comment: Just drop the { } from the function arguments. For this case, you dont need them.

Comment: hi, @yuanyuan & StamatisDeliyannis my primary intention was not just to set the default value for parameters, but the order & number of parameter functions can accept without using '_' (underscores) which can be normally handled. plz refer to my code snippet [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wasitshafi/xb1gvz5d/1/), I am going to append the code snippet in question as well.

Comment: Typo mistake in above comment: '...(underscores) which can't be normally handled.'

Comment: I guess you can use `Object.entries()`, take a look of this page [MDN Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 0):

Since your function expects an object with keys “name”, “subjects” and “university”, you need to call the function by passing an object.

For a React component, all props are part of the “props” object. The props object has the keys that you passed, as well as a few generic keys unique to React components (like children)